# Counting the rows in a data frame based on integer ranges

Tags: r

I have a data frame that lists a bunch of objects and their values.

```
             Name NumCpu MemoryMB
1 BEAVERTN-SVR-C5      1     3072
2 BEAVERTN-SVR-UK      4     4096
3 BEAVERTN-SVR-JV      1     1024
```

I want to take my data frame and create a new column that groups these numbers by ranges.

```
Ranges: 0-1024, 1025-2048, 2049-4096
```

And then output the counts of those ranges into a new data frame:

```
Range     Count
   0-1024     1
1025-2048     0
2049-4096     2
```

I learn by doing, so this is a real work problem I'm trying to use R to solve. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Data

```
DF <- structure(list(Name = c("BEAVERTN-SVR-C5", "BEAVERTN-SVR-UK", 
"BEAVERTN-SVR-JV"), NumCpu = c(1L, 4L, 1L), MemoryMB = c(3072L, 
4096L, 1024L), Range = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("(0,1.02e+03]", 
"(1.02e+03,2.05e+03]", "(2.05e+03,4.1e+03]"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", 
"NumCpu", "MemoryMB", "Range"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have a look at `?cut` and `?table`. Maybe like `DF$Range = cut(DF$MemoryMB, c(0, (10:12)^2)); table(DF$Range)`

Comment: @Frank your exponent may be backwards

Comment: @rawr Ha, good catch. Thanks

Comment: @rawr, thanks for the update with the data frame details!

Comment: @Frank, playing around with these commands some more. Thank you!!